# How to perform post hoc test (pairwise comparison) of model by betabin in aod?

Tags: r

Because of overdispersion, I try to use beta-binomial method fit the data. However, it seems emmeans and glht did not support the model by betabin. I test by the example data orob2 in aod, and want to do comparison in seed.

```
data(orob2)
fm1 <- betabin(cbind(y, n - y) ~ seed, ~ 1, data = orob2)
emmeans(fm1, pairwise~seed, adjust="tukey")

Error in (function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"), : Can't handle an object of class “glimML” Use help("models", package = "emmeans") for information on supported models.
```

Is there any other package support this model?

Thank you!

Comment: ```Because of overdispersion, I try to use beta-binomial method fit``` this doesn't seem like a good justification. In any case, I think yours is a statistical question because you want to know how to estimate the difference in means properly.. it goes beyond plugging in a package. Try deleting this question and posting on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I voted to migrate it but it may not go through fast enough

Comment: I just want to ask which package can be used, I have try to ask in statistical part, but was closed because of off-topic